# Outer automorphism group of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm reading about the special unitary Lie algebras, and seen it said that complex conjugation is not an inner automorphism of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ for $n>2$. If there an easy way to see this?

I understand that the automorphism would be inner if there is some $g \in SU(n)$ such that $gXg^{-1} = \bar{X}$ for all $X \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$, is there a simple way to see that no such $g$ exists? Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Yes, there is an argument given in Jacobson's book on Lie algebras, on page $282$ before Theorem $5$. Basically, assuming that the two automorphisms coincide (the outer and an inner), Schur's lemma over $\mathbb{C}$ and dimension reasons imply that $n=2$, a contradiction.